# OpenABE C++ Library: Undefined Reference Error

Tags: c++

I have successfully installed the OpenABE Library - https://github.com/zeutro/openabe

But when I try to compile my own program or run the example - https://github.com/zeutro/openabe/blob/master/examples/test_cp.cpp

> g++ test.cpp

I get the  Error:

> /tmp/ccAcWSoq.o: In function `main':
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to`oabe::InitializeOpenABE()'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `oabe::OpenABECryptoContext::OpenABECryptoContext(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0xea): undefined reference to`oabe::OpenABECryptoContext::generateParams()'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x1bf): undefined reference to `oabe::OpenABECryptoContext::keygen(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x27b): undefined reference to`oabe::OpenABECryptoContext::encrypt(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >&)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x2dd): undefined reference to `oabe::OpenABECryptoContext::decrypt(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x385): undefined reference to`oabe::ShutdownOpenABE()'
>   /tmp/ccAcWSoq.o: In function `oabe::OpenABECryptoContext::~OpenABECryptoContext()':
>   test.cpp:(.text._ZN4oabe20OpenABECryptoContextD2Ev[_ZN4oabe20OpenABECryptoContextD5Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to`vtable for oabe::OpenABECryptoContext'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Here is the code - test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

#include <openabe/openabe.h>
#include <openabe/zsymcrypto.h>



using namespace std;
using namespace oabe;
using namespace oabe::crypto;




int main(int argc, char **argv){

    InitializeOpenABE();

    OpenABECryptoContext cpabe("CP-ABE");

    string ct, pt1 = "plaintext", pt2;

    cpabe.generateParams();

    cpabe.keygen("|attr1|attr2","key0");

    cpabe.encrypt("attr1 and attr2",pt1,ct);

    bool result =  cpabe.decrypt("key0",ct,pt2);


    assert(result && pt1 == pt2);

    cout << "Message: " << pt2 << endl;

    ShutdownOpenABE();

    return 0;

}
```

Am I even compiling the file correctly?
Or is there any other issue that I cannot seem to identify?

Comment: I don't know this library, but: Is there a library file you need to add to your gcc (link) command? There usually is.

Comment: Please have a look into [zeutro/openabe/examples/Makefile](https://github.com/zeutro/openabe/blob/master/examples/Makefile). There are lib. paths `-L${ZROOT}/deps/root/lib -L${ZROOT}/root/lib` and libs `-lcrypto -lrelic -lrelic_ec -lopenabe` you need for linking.